# Spacy 2.0.11 has requirement regex==2017.4.5, but you'll have regex 2017.11.9 which is incompatible

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am using `MacOS High Sierra` and recently got this issue while any `python` related installations. I am trying to update setup tools

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools

>>>spacy 2.0.11 has requirement regex==2017.4.5, but you'll have regex 2017.11.9 which is incompatible.
```

Please suggest how to fix this issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
pip install regex==2017.4.5
```

Comment: I got error :- 
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for regex

failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/7k/3qybm9cj5tz_thhs_05kt26w0000gn/T/pip-install-z2xxv4kx/regex/

Answer (score 4):

A possibility is that both `spacy` and `regex` `packages` were not updated together, causing discrepancies.

Try upgrading `pip` and install `spacy` again.

```
pip install --upgrade pip

pip install spacy
```